# When to use controllers?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, controllers

This is what I'm doing right now:

- Implemented different router modules for different routes
- Each router has it's own sets of MongooseModels.
- Handler the request (req,res) and interact with the MongooseModel via statics and methods

This is what I want to know:

Almost every example is see where Mongoose,Express are involved, they seem to follow the MVC pattern, which places "Controllers" in between. Now, I have statics and methods defined in each MongooseModel and are capable of handling only the (req.body) part of my original (req) (Because, that's what they only need, right?). Extract the result, and the rest is done by the router.

So, do I really need to place Controllers in between as my MongooseModel is already doing the same job?

Thanks.